# identifying when new window closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller.js I have opened a new window with `window.open();`

I need to start loading symbol and after closing the opened window with  `window.open();`, I need to stop the loading symbol. is it possible.my sample code is as follows.

```
$scope.showAuditLoadingDiv = true;
window.open("newPage", "_BLANK", "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
$scope.showAuditLoadingDiv = false;
```

Comment: You can check by `if(window.closed)`

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` returns a window object... you can check for it's 'closed'-property. Sample Code:

```
var google = window.open("https://www.google.de/");
console.log(google);

setInterval(function () {
    console.log(google.closed);
}, 300);
```

When the new window is closed, the closed-property is set to true.